# What does "thesis" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "direction"? I don't find anything here that fits. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thesis

> "Overall, he's optimistic about the increasing flow of dollars into health care, especially for efforts that support the shift from volume-based care (payment based on tests and procedures) to value-based care (payment based on outcomes). But he thinks that Silicon Valley has a long way to go to evolve its **thesis**, to ensure it's more inclusive of all Americans."
>
> (Source: [this link](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/09/medicaid-chief-andrey-ostrovsky-silicon-valley-missing-unicorns.html))

Comment: It means either a hypothetical proposition or a piece of writing. Why do you think it should mean "direction"? Why do you think that dictionary, which you quoted, does not have anything?

Comment: I don't see any mention of what this thesis is or any sort of reference to the thesis the article talks about. So, I'm forced to conclude that the writer does not know what the thesis is either or maybe even what the word means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dictionary:

> **Thesis** a proposition stated or put forward for consideration, especially one to be discussed and proved or to be maintained against objections

I personally would have gone with **Hypothesis**: *interpretation of a practical situation or condition taken as the ground for action*

The article is discussing how "Silicon Valley" (e.g. computer programmers)  should create health care apps -
They assume most users are rich and healthy.

> **Health-technology for those in need**
>
> The health-technology sector is booming, with investors pouring $4.2 billion into the space last year alone.
>
> But only a tiny fraction of these technologies are targeted to disadvantaged communities. Fitbit activity bracelets or doctor-scheduling apps aren't particularly useful for those who are homeless, or lack reliable Internet access.

From the subtitles:

> Medicaid's chief medical officer Andrey Ostrovsky said Silicon Valley has a long way to go to evolve its health care thesis
>
> Most health apps are targeted to healthy, wealthy populations rather than on low-income groups.
>
> There are many huge IT businesses to be built that improve outdated technology processes for Medicaid

ending on

> **But he thinks that Silicon Valley has a long way to go to evolve its thesis, to ensure it's more inclusive of all Americans**.